# Loading multiple html5 videos in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html5-video

When I load my page with a bunch of videos I see a Chrome status bar showing 'Waiting for available socket' and the page is pending. If I remove some video tags, it loads fine. My video tags are simple like this:

```
<video>
      <source src='/video/video.webm'/>
</video>
```

I have searched Google, but had no luck.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Not sure if you need to specify codecs. Try this: `<source src='...' type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />`

Comment: This might be an issue of you trying to pull too many video files from your server. Chrome can only open 8 (or somewhere around that) concurrent HTTP connections to a given domain.

Comment: See http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top. They list 6 on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29639535/1339426

Adding `preload="none"` to your video tag will solve this. *Although I would prefer an option that allowed me to preload the metadata.*