# "Waiting for available socket", fix from the server end

Tags: apache

I am accessing my PHP/Apache website from Chrome. And Chrome refuses to load the page, saying "Waiting for available socket".

Other pages on this same virtual host also have the problem.

Other virtual hosts on the same server load perfectly fine.

Please advise how I can fix this.

Comment: Sounds like your browser thinks it already has N busy sockets to that domain, can you tell what's running?

Answer (score 10):

According to various sources, Chrome opens a maximum of 6 simultaneous connections to the same server. Possible solutions include

- Host data on different virtual hosts on the same machine.
- Consolidate content to be loaded to require fewer connections (for example, put everything in a single .data file for Emscripten)
- Make sure you don't have too many `<video>` or `<audio>` tags marked with the attribute `preload="auto"`.
- Adjust Chrome to permit up to 32 connections. [Policy List](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#MaxConnectionsPerProxy)

Related question:
[Chrome hangs after certain amount of data transfered - waiting for available socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679968/chrome-hangs-after-certain-amount-of-data-transfered-waiting-for-available-soc)

Comment: You got this right as it is not just a front-end issue. But a real solution to this is in back-end alone and I am looking for another solution apart from use of virtual hosts.

Comment: 10x, I've fixed that setting `<audio preload=none>`