# Chrome waiting for available sockets, Firefox is fine

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, sockets, http

We have a Wordpress based website ([rendeljkinait.hu](https://rendeljkinait.hu)), and we face freezing issues while editing articles when using Chrome. When I hit the save button for the 7th time without page reload, the article editor freezes during save and I get "waiting for available socket" error in Chrome. No matter how long I wait, the editor won't save until I reload the page. When I'm using Firefox, everything is fine, no matter how much I hit the save button. Current Wordpress version is 5.2.3, but error occured in former versions too.

I investigated the error, and found it is caused because Chrome never closes the open sockets until I reload the page. So until hitting the button 6 times everything is fine, since Chrome and other modern browsers allow to have maximum 6 paralell connection to a single host. But after I press the button for the 7th time, there is no space for another connection, so Chrome is waiting for the older connections to get closed, but it never happens. 
[Here's a screenshot from net log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa5Lu.png)

Using Firefox I observed that it always closes the connection after the save is successful, so only 1 connection is active all the time, it never exceeds the 6 paralell connection limit. I attached Chrome netlog file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ujhIlqUVMfFtgGyxDG5ka7n3SrFQukIQ), you can view it [here](https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/#import). I also attached a video showing Firefox closing the connection [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EKwBmfQLv7lYGxl9wE5SZcYcWtYYlRQb) (107.6.*.** is our servers IP).

For various reasons we have to use Chrome, so I would like to find a solution for this problem, but I'm completely stuck. Does anyone have a suggestion what could cause the problem and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Waiting for available socket", fix from the server end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445360/waiting-for-available-socket-fix-from-the-server-end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might find this topic with similar problem: seems like it was a Wordpress bug, a Wordpress update solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems with chrome and gutenberg. 
It is impossible to do any heavy editing on the site, so I use firefox for all admin related stuff.

Haven't found a solution either...

Comment: That's sad. You think it's an issue of Gutenberg and we have no chance to solve it by our own, we should wait for Wordpress updates? Now we use Firefox for editing too, but it's kinda uncomfortable to switch browsers all the time...