# Waiting for available socket... (Chrome + Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, websocket

**Context**

I am updating my website (a WordPress site). I am occasionally reloading the page as I make changes to it.

My Chrome is Version 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit).

**Problem**

Typically, after perhaps 3-5 updates and subsequent reloads, I am not able to load the webpage anymore. I am simply seeing

> Waiting for available socket...

At the bottom of the page. I can wait as long as I want, but nothing happens.

In fact, if I try to open any subpage from the page, Chrome just keeps showing the same error.

If I reopen the same page in an incognito-window or in a different browser, it opens without any issues.

**Tried solutions**

*Restart Chrome*? This works. But now my workflow is becoming really inconvenient as after every ~5 updates I have to restart my browser setup.

*Open a new incognito window*? Works, but same issues as above.

*Open in a different browser*? Works, but same issues as above.

❌ *Open in a new tab?* Error persists.

❌ *Flush socket pools?* Many posts recommend going to `chrome://net-internals/#sockets` and flushing socket pools. No impact for me, unfortunately.

❌ *Disable antivirus*? Issue persists.

❌ *Clear cookies and cache*? Issue persists.

❌ *Disable all extensions*? Issue persists.

**My question**

What would you try next? Or how do you even diagnose this problem further?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Waiting for available socket", fix from the server end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445360/waiting-for-available-socket-fix-from-the-server-end)