# Angular HttpClient leaving sockets open

Tags: angular, apache, rest, google-chrome

I have an Angular service to handle my REST calls to an Apache server.  There are instances when a user makes several REST calls in a row.  When this happens, Chrome will hold a socket open for each request.  The sockets are kept open for 60 seconds and are not reused.  Eventually a limit is hit and all subsequent requests are held as "pending" until a socket is cleared.  I have researched the Chrome "Waiting for available socket" issue, however all of the solutions point towards a client side fix of clearing sockets through Chrome.  This issue does NOT appear when hitting my REST API on my localhost Apache server.

I would think there has to be a server side solution or a way in Angular to clear or reset the socket.

I am using:
Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 
Ubuntu 16.04
Apache version 2.4.7

Comment: Stop making so many requests.

Comment: I'm assuming you saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679968/chrome-hangs-after-certain-amount-of-data-transfered-waiting-for-available-soc), but just in case...there it is.

Comment: I saw the post @trueCamelType.  The solutions aren't viable for me.  I don't know why this happens on a production server and NOT when testing in my development environment on LOCALHOST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sockets were being kept open by a secondary script that would run after the return of the REST call.  These scripts were timing out (missing resource on the server) at 60 seconds.  So after I initially made 6 (Chrome socket limit) REST calls that returned successfully...the secondary script was keeping the socket open until it timed out on the server.