# iFrame not loading properly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I am attempting to show a simple mockup to a potential client of how he could stream media from his own online radio station to a page. The radio station was built using an external site and in Safari rendering the station's share link in an iFrame works perfectly, and plays immediately on page load without the user having to do anything. Here is the pure html code; there's no JS for this page now:

```
<iframe src="https://lucasdraft.out.airtime.pro/lucasdraft_a" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The CSS:

```
iframe {
        height: 50px;
        width: 200px;
        float: right;
}
```

But in Chrome, half the time when I try to load the page the iframe doesn't show up at all and the page loads continuously with the status at bottom left displaying "Waiting for available socket"- again this never happens on Safari. When it does load in Chrome, instead of showing the basic media player from the external source it shows a sort of gray semi-circle with three dots. If I click this gray blob it begins playing, but this is very un-intuitive to a user not to mention ugly. I assume this is a security feature in Chrome but haven't found any reliable way of fixing it. Increasing the size of the iframe does not change anything.

Safari (working as expected):
[image]

Chrome loading error:
[image]

Chrome with cache cleared, after loading the iframe:

[image]

Thanks and anything helps in fixing this pesky error!

Comment: Run a local server, testing off file protocol leads to problems

Comment: @epascareloo Both issues in Chrome still occur when running from a local server, specifically Live Server out of VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

For the Waiting for available socket, a quick google search got me this answer. [Chrome hangs after certain amount of data transfered - waiting for available socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679968/chrome-hangs-after-certain-amount-of-data-transfered-waiting-for-available-soc) It's always a good idea to google something before asking.

For the visual problem. the Url in your Iframe is calling a video. Different browsers use different style for their video player. Chrome just needs a little bit more height. I find that 100px works well.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu! I google'd for a day and a half but guess I wasn't using the correct search terms. The height fix worked well for the video player- I had tried quite large iFrames previously but maybe the loading issue kept it from rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue(Worked in safari but not in chrome). In my case the issue was the ***Ad-blocker*** . Ad-blocker usually writes scripts to override the iframe styles.

Once I disable the ad-blocker or load the project in incognito(private browser) window the iframe content loaded successfully.